# Idiomatic way to store two related values of the same type

Tags: c++, c++11, std-pair, idioms, stdarray

This will be a pretty simple question: in C++03, I would store two values of the same type with `std::pair`. However, having to repeat the type twice is somehow a bother when I want both of my values to be of the same type. Now, with C++11, we have `std::array`. Would it be more idiomatic to write this:

```
std::array<int, 2> foo;
```

...instead of that:

```
std::pair<int, int> foo;
```

...when the aim is to store two related data (picture for example the result of a function solving a quadratic equation)?

Comment: IMO an array would be better suited to a list of elements. A pair suits better if you have just 2 "related" members.

Comment: An array is better but still not great, see my answer.

Comment: If you have only one such pair, I would use an array. "Easier" write/store. If you have multiple pairs, I would of course std::pair and store them in a vector…

Comment: @Morwenn: Haha... hopefully my explanation of why `pair` is objective instead of subjective :P

Comment: @Mehrdad Well it is. I really do like it and it makes sense :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### I don't think there's any data type suitable for this in either the standard library or in Boost.

`pair<T, T>` is ***definitely wrong:***
`make_pair(1, 2) == make_pair(2, 1)` should be *true* if these represent the roots of a polynomial!

For the same reason, an array/vector won't work either, unless you change the comparison behavior.

So I'd say make a `bag<T, N>` data type that represents a `multiset<T>` with a fixed size, kind of like how `array<T, N>` represents a `vector<T>` with a fixed size.

Since the size is small, you can just do everything by brute force (comparison, equality checking, etc.).

Comment: Well, too bad there isn't such a type in Boost then.

Comment: Yeah it's unfortunate.

Answer (score 1):

I'd still use pair to indicate that one value is related to the other. Array does not convey that meaning to me.

Answer (score 0):

Precisely for idiomatic reasons, I would suggest using `pair` a denotes that both values are related while `array` is more related to a list of values (in my humble opinion).

For example, in your suggested usage, the relation between both values would be the quadratic function itself.

Answer (score 0):

`std::pair` makes sense if you have relation between two items, and you want to describe that relation.

However, in your case I would use `std::array`, as two solutions of quadratic equation don't have any relationship between each other (I can see the relationship between the solutions and the equatiation, but not between two solutions).

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the larger context.

In the example you mentioned I'd go with `std::array`, because then you can also template the function on the degree of the equation:

```
template <int N>
std::array<double, N> solveEquation(const Polynomial<N>& poly);
```

Answer (score -1):

I'd say the corresponding C++11 abstraction of `std::pair<>` is `std::tuple<>`, since a pair is just a special case of tuple.

`std::pair<>` doesn't hold equal types necessarily, BTW.

Comment: Well, my question is about the specific case of exactly two values of the same type; this doesn't really answer anything :/

Comment: @Morwenn But `std::array<>` can in no way be seen as a replacement for `std::pair<>`. As mentioned the abstraction is `std::tuple`. You should use either this, or stick to `std::pair` to express the semantics of your case. Sorry, I could try to clarify this in my answer, if you wish.